# scanLeft using HMap in shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm using shapeless `HMap` as the underlying structure of a case class acting as an aggregator for other objects sharing the same parent. The parent trait allows access to an Int-valued property called `arity`. I would like to use `scanLeft` on the `HMap` to calculate the cumulative `arity`s of the objects in the `HList`. I was successful in writing the `Poly` objects allowing to calculate the sum of all `arity`s using `foldLeft`, but when trying to apply the same concepts to `scanLeft` it doesn't work anymore.

Q1: Does anyone see how I should modify `pointAccumulate` in order to support `scanLeft` operations? I'm expecting `lookup` to be something like this `Nat(2) :: Nat(5) :: Nat(8) :: HNil` (using the example below).

Q2: I will use `lookup` afterwards to search the index of an element knowing the cumulative arity in the combined structure. Given this, would it be ok to work with HList or I should make sure that I get `lookup` as a List[Int]?

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.{At, LeftFolder, LeftScanner}

object Point { type Point = (Double, Double) }

import Point._

sealed trait Shape {
    val arity: Int
}

case class Line(p0: Point, p1: Point) extends Shape {
    val arity = 2
}

case class Triangle(p0: Point, p1: Point, p2: Point) extends Shape {
    val arity = 3
}

case class Canvas[L <: HList](shapes: L)
                             (implicit
                              val ev: LUBConstraint[L, Shape],
                              val lf: LeftFolder.Aux[L, Int, pointAccumulate.type, Int],
                              val ls: LeftScanner[L, Int, pointAccumulate.type]) {

    lazy val parameterCount: Int = shapes.foldLeft(0)(pointAccumulate)

    lazy val lookup = shapes.scanLeft(0)(pointAccumulate)
}

object pointCount extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[T <: Shape] = at[T](_.arity)
}

object pointAccumulate extends Poly2 {
    implicit def default[T <: Shape](implicit pt: pointCount.Case.Aux[T, Int]) =
        at[Int, T] { (i, p) => i + pointCount(p) }
}

object App {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val l0 = Line((-2, 2), (2, -2))
        val tr1 = Triangle((0,0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
        val tr2 = Triangle((1,1), (1, 2), (2, 1))

        val c = Canvas(l0 :: tr1 :: tr2 :: HNil)
        println(c.lookup)
    }
}
```

Comment: For `scanLeft`, the `Poly2` parameters must be switched: `at[T, Int] { (p, i) => i + pointCount(p)`

Comment: @devkat you're right, it works with your change. thanks for this! if you want, you can add your reply as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the hint from @devkat. Here is the working piece of code

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.{At, LeftFolder, LeftScanner}

object Point { type Point = (Double, Double) }

import Point._

sealed trait Shape {
    val arity: Int
}

case class Line(p0: Point, p1: Point) extends Shape {
    val arity = 2
}

case class Triangle(p0: Point, p1: Point, p2: Point) extends Shape {
    val arity = 3
}

case class Canvas[L <: HList, LL <: HList](shapes: L)
                             (implicit
                              val ev: LUBConstraint[L, Shape],
                              val lf: LeftFolder.Aux[L, Int, pointAccumulate.type, Int],
                              val ls: LeftScanner.Aux[L, Int, pointAccumulate.type, LL],
                              val ev2: LUBConstraint[LL, Int]) {

    lazy val parameterCount: Int = shapes.foldLeft(0)(pointAccumulate)

    lazy val lookup = shapes.scanLeft(0)(pointAccumulate)
}

object pointCount extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[T <: Shape] = at[T](_.arity)
}

object pointAccumulate extends Poly2 {
    implicit def default1[T <: Shape](implicit pt: pointCount.Case.Aux[T, Int]) =
        at[T, Int] { (p, i) => i + pointCount(p) }

    implicit def default2[T <: Shape](implicit pt: pointCount.Case.Aux[T, Int]) =
        at[Int, T] { (i, p) => i + pointCount(p) }
}

object App2 {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val l0 = Line((-2, 2), (2, -2))
        val tr1 = Triangle((0,0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
        val tr2 = Triangle((1,1), (1, 2), (2, 1))

        val c = Canvas(l0 :: tr1 :: tr2 :: HNil)
        println(c.parameterCount)
        println(c.lookup)
    }
}
```